# Android - ActionBar icon not showhing

Tags: android, android-actionbar, icons

I have trouble seeing the icons in the ActionBar.
I also read around here in StackOverFlow, but nothing...

Here is my action.xml

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto" >

<item
    android:id="@+id/addAct"
    android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_input_add"
    android:background="@null"
    app:showAsAction="always"
    android:title="@string/add"
    />
<item
    android:id="@+id/searchAct"
    android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_search"
    app:showAsAction="ifRoom"
    android:title="Cerca"
    android:actionViewClass="android.widget.SearchView"
    />

<item
    android:id="@+id/visualizza"
    android:title="@string/txtVisualizza"
    app:showAsAction="always"
    >

</item>
```

Here, is AndroiManifest.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="11"
    android:maxSdkVersion="21"/>

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".WriteActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_write" >
    </activity>
</application>
```

Here, MainActivity:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity { ...
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.action, menu);
    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}
```

In the xml code, I have used the app for ShowAsAction, but this not seems be the problem.
Thanks for any help :)

Comment: change `extends ActionBarActivity` instead of `extends Activity` @Leonardo

Comment: Check my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28855283/how-display-logo-on-action-bar/28855386#28855386

Comment: what is the there you are using?

Comment: Ok, but I get an Exception:
java.lang.IllegalStateException: You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with this activity

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are developing app for material design ( Target SDK = 21).
It does not support Activity.

So change `extends Activity` to `extends ActionBarActivity`.

Now your menu will be visible.
And you can edit action bar using `getSupportActionBar()`.

Comment: Why I get java.lang.IllegalStateException: You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with this activity.?

Comment: What is your Target SDK? And you activity `extends Activity` or `extends ActionBarActivity`? @LeonardoShofflen

Comment: minSDK = 11, maxSDK = 21.
I am using API 21
extends ActionBarActivity

Comment: Using `ActionBarActivity` requires the AppCompat theme to be applied. You  may have Holo theme in your styles.xml @LeonardoShofflen

Comment: Are you trying to implement material design? @LeonardoShofflen

Comment: I resolved <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
Thanks! =)